# Office Fabric UI MessageBanner selection inconsistency

Tags: javascript, jquery, office-js, office-ui-fabric

I'm having trouble when working with Office Fabric UI `MessageBanner` component. Why can I instantiate an element returned by both jQuery and `document.querySelector` with the `ChoiceFieldGroup`, but only `document.querySelector` works with `MessageBanner`?

This is the file `test.html`:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //This works:
    var $ChoiceFieldGroupElements = $(".ms-ChoiceFieldGroup");
    //This also works:
    //var $ChoiceFieldGroupElements = document.querySelector(".ms-ChoiceFieldGroup");

    //This works:
    var $mb = document.querySelector('.ms-MessageBanner');
    //This doesn't work:
    //var $mb = $('.ms-MessageBanner');

    // Just the components' initialization
    for (var i = 0; i < $ChoiceFieldGroupElements.length; i++) {
        new fabric["ChoiceFieldGroup"]($ChoiceFieldGroupElements[i]);
    }
  var MessageBanner =   new fabric["MessageBanner"]($mb);
});
```

This is the file `test.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
    <title>Fabric Test</title>

        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://static2.sharepointonline.com/files/fabric/office-ui-fabric-js/1.4.0/css/fabric.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://static2.sharepointonline.com/files/fabric/office-ui-fabric-js/1.4.0/css/fabric.components.min.css">
    <script src="https://static2.sharepointonline.com/files/fabric/office-ui-fabric-js/1.4.0/js/fabric.min.js"></script>

        <script src="test.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <br />
    <div id="title" class="ms-font-xxl ms-fontColor-neutralSecondary ms-fontWeight-semilight">Title</div>
    <br /><br />
    <p id="body" class="ms-font-m-plus ms-fontColor-neutralTertiary">Body text:</p>

    <div id="choicefieldgroup" class="ms-ChoiceFieldGroup" role="radiogroup">
        <ul class="ms-ChoiceFieldGroup-list">
            <li class="ms-RadioButton">
                <input tabindex="-1" type="radio" class="ms-RadioButton-input">
                <label role="radio"
                       class="ms-RadioButton-field"
                       tabindex="0"
                       aria-checked="false"
                       name="choicefieldgroup">
                    <span id="spn1" class="ms-Label">Option 1</span>
                </label>
            </li>
            <li class="ms-RadioButton">
                <input tabindex="-1" type="radio" class="ms-RadioButton-input">
                <label role="radio"
                       class="ms-RadioButton-field"
                       tabindex="0"
                       aria-checked="false"
                       name="choicefieldgroup">
                    <span class="ms-Label">Option 2</span>
                </label>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="ms-MessageBanner" id="notification-popup">
        <div class="ms-MessageBanner-content">
                <div class="ms-MessageBanner-text">
                        <div class="ms-MessageBanner-clipper">
                                <div class="ms-font-m-plus ms-fontWeight-semibold" id="notification-header">Notification Title</div>
                                <div class="ms-font-m ms-fontWeight-semilight" id="notification-body">Notification Body</div>
                        </div>
                </div>
                <button class="ms-MessageBanner-expand" style="display:none"><i class="ms-Icon ms-Icon--chevronsDown"></i> </button>
                <div class="ms-MessageBanner-action"></div>
        </div>
        <button class="ms-MessageBanner-close"> <i class="ms-Icon ms-Icon--x"></i> </button>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I would advice to post this question directly into developers resource: [office-ui-fabric-js](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-ui-fabric-js/issues). You'll get your answer much quicker, they are pretty responsive to the issues

Comment: Thanks, Slava, I've figured out what I did wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out I'm mixing jQuery elements with Fabric elements.

The error happens in the initialization of Fabric object, not in the selector.

If your element is HTML, you build his component using the syntax:

```
new fabric['ComponentName'](document.querySelector('.class-name'));
```

However, if you have a jQuery object, you must pass the raw HTML to the Fabric method by using `[0]`:

```
new fabric['ComponentName']($('.class-name')[0]);
```